# Does function order matter in Doctrine2 Query Builder?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, orm, doctrine-orm

I have two entities `Order` and `Shipment`. Each Order has one Shipment and visa versa. I am trying to get a query of Orders that are pending. Here are the criteria:

- The Order has been sent (and not just saved)
- The Order has not been cancelled
- The Order doesn't have a Shipment
- OR The Order has a Shipment

  - But the Shipment has not been sent (it was just saved)
  - If the Shipment has been sent, it also has been cancelled

Here is the query I have come up with:

```php
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class OrderRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function findPending($id)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
            ->addSelect('s')
            ->leftJoin('MyApp\\Model\\Entity\\Shipment', 's')
            ->orderBy('o.date_sent', 'DESC')

            // Order has been sent
            ->where($qb->expr()->neq('o.date_sent',':date_sent'))
            ->setParameter('date_sent', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')

            // Order was not cancelled
            ->where($qb->expr()->eq('o.date_cancelled',':date_cancelled'))
            ->setParameter('date_cancelled', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')

            // Order does not have a shipment
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->isNull('s.order'))

            // OR Shipment has not been sent
            ->orWhere($qb->expr()->neq('s.date_sent', ':ship_date_sent'))
            ->setParameter('ship_date_sent', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')

            // AND Shipment has not been cancelled
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('s.date_cancelled',':ship_date_cancelled'))
            ->setParameter('ship_date_cancelled', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')

            ->setMaxResults(6)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

It seems to be working, but I don't have much data to test it with. I am worried about the last `->andWhere()` statement, to see if the Shipment has not been cancelled. If I use 'and', I am worried it will only return Orders with Shipments that "have not been sent and have not been cancelled" instead of "have not been sent or if sent, has not been cancelled". If I change the `->andWhere()` to `->orWhere()` I assume it will return Orders with Shipments that "have been sent but are not cancelled".

My main concern is how the order of the query functions effect the query. Also, should `where()` only be used once? I don't see the difference between `where()` and `andWhere()`?

If my question isn't clear enough, let me know and I will update it.

Thank you in advance.

## Update

I have dug a little deeper and come up with this new query. Which I think would work?

```
public function findPending($id)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->addSelect('s')
        ->leftJoin('MyApp\\Model\\Entity\\Shipment', 's')
        ->orderBy('o.date_sent', 'DESC')

        // Order has been sent and was not cancelled
        ->where($qb->expr()->andX(
            $qb->expr()->eq('o.date_cancelled','0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
            $qb->expr()->neq('o.date_sent','0000-00-00 00:00:00')
            ))

        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX(
            // Order doesn't have a shipment
            $qb->expr()->isNull('s.order'),
            // OR Order has a shipment
            $qb->expr()->orX(
                // Shipment has not been sent
                $qb->expr()->eq('s.date_sent','0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
                // OR Shipment has been sent AND it was cancelled
                $qb->expr()->andX(
                    $qb->expr()->neq('s.date_sent','0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
                    $qb->expr()->eq('s.date_cancelled','0000-00-00 00:00:00')
                    )
                )
            ))

        ->setMaxResults(6)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    return $qb;
}
```

Comment: you miss an `andWhere` in the *Order was not cancelled* condition

Comment: @Matteo In the paragraph below my code I ask about the difference between `where` and `andWhere` and if you are only allowed to use `where` once, is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

yes, **where** can only be used once, so if the **andWhere** (or **orWhere**) are conditional but could be used multiple times, you should probably use **where 1=1**